# Unable to match this string "18% on $25.56" with this regex ".*(\d+)%.*\$(\d+)(\.\d+)?$". What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, regex, express

I'm trying to get the numbers out of a string that user inputs for calculating tip. The query could be "Calculate 18% tip on $25.56" or simply "18% $25.56"

I've built up this regex

```
.*(\d+)%.*\$(\d+)(\.\d+)?$
```

However, the first capturing group doesn't capture 18, just 8. What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:** Based on the answer below, I made my regex more error resilient. For matching a string like this

> "Calculate18sdaasa%onasda$dsada25dasda.56aaddsadas dsad asdadas 18 sadasd 23 asdasd .56 asdasd"

I now have the regex as

`.*?(\d+).*?%.*?\$.*?(\d+).*?(\.\d+).*`

This captures the first three numbers 18, 25 and .56 which is what I need.

Comment: Can you please make your question somewhat clearer; you have one example string in the title of your question, then you have two more different strings in your actual question. Put them all in the question (not one in the title). Are these three the only possible variations?

Comment: Regarding your edit: Well done! :)

Comment: However, note the `.*\$` part in your edit. There, `.*` is still greedy, so the regex would match `"Calculate 18 sda asa% on asda $dsada 25 dasd a.56 and calculate 20 aa% on bb$cc 30 duda .99"` completely **once** (not sure if that is a valid string in your scenario, though).

Comment: By the way, you can try your Regex patterns easily online. There are several services, such as [Regex101](http://regex101.com/) for example.

Comment: @elgonzo - Yep you're right, I missed that greedy part. That string you posted should be invalid but I'll have to do some validation to not try matching that. Basically I'm trying to calculate tip based on user input. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `.*` in the beginning of your RegEx is greedy, and that `(\d+)` will also be satisfied with only matching a single-digit number. Thus, the starting `.*` kind of "steals" all but the last digit of your first number while `(\d+)` still matches the last digit of the first number.

Do it like this instead:

```
.*?(\d+)%.*\$(\d+)(\.\d+)?$
```

`.*?` is non-greedy, that means, it will match as few characters as possible to satisfy the pattern.

Comment: Ah, wonderful! Thank you for the explanation. I have to look into this greedy/non-greedy stuff more.

Comment: Based on this, I made my regex more error resilient. For matching a string like this "Calculate 18 sda asa% on asda $dsada 25 dasd a.56" I now have the regex as .*?(\d+).*?%.*\$.*?(\d+).*?(\.\d+)?$

Answer (score -1):

Try this following regex pattern:

```
\d+.?\d+
```

Comment: Hmm... the OP used three groups in his Regex, which you just ignored in your answer. What makes you so certain that the OP does not want to process the results of these groups?